# How do I make a non-blocking socket call in C# to determine connection status?

Tags: c#, sockets

the MSDN docs for the Connected property on Socket say the following:

> The value of the Connected property
>   reflects the state of the connection
>   as of the most recent operation. If
>   you need to determine the current
>   state of the connection, make a
>   nonblocking, zero-byte Send call. If
>   the call returns successfully or
>   throws a WAEWOULDBLOCK error code
>   (10035), then the socket is still
>   connected; otherwise, the socket is no
>   longer connected.

I need to determine the current state of the connection - how do i make a non-blocking, zero-byte send call?

Comment: Would using HTTP Keepalive be any good?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example at the bottom of MSDN documentation for the [Socket.Connected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.connected.aspx) property (at least the .NET 3.5 version) shows how to do this:

```
// .Connect throws an exception if unsuccessful
client.Connect(anEndPoint);

// This is how you can determine whether a socket is still connected.
bool blockingState = client.Blocking;
try
{
    byte [] tmp = new byte[1];

    client.Blocking = false;
    client.Send(tmp, 0, 0);
    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
}
catch (SocketException e) 
{
    // 10035 == WSAEWOULDBLOCK
    if (e.NativeErrorCode.Equals(10035))
        Console.WriteLine("Still Connected, but the Send would block");
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disconnected: error code {0}!", e.NativeErrorCode);
    }
}
finally
{
    client.Blocking = blockingState;
}

 Console.WriteLine("Connected: {0}", client.Connected);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Socket.BeginSend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginsend.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just providing additional info based on experience: The comments at the bottom of versions 3.5 and 4 of that documentation page for [Socket.Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.connected.aspx) describe my experience - the example simply didn't work. Really wish I knew why it works for some and not others.

As a work-around, despite what the documentation says, I changed the sample to actually send the 1 byte with no flags. This successfully updated the state of Connected property, and is equivalent to sending a keep-alive packet at an interval.